# AudioQueueEnqueueBufferWithParameters ignoring inStartTime

Tags: ios, core-audio

I'm trying to use AudioQueueEnqueueBufferWithParameters with the inStartTime parameter to delay the start of playing each buffer.  As shown below, it is playing back without the intended delays. My inStartTime is incrementing correctly, but the call is returning the actual start time as essentially back-to-back with the previous buffer. The sound I am playing fits in a single buffer, so I am enqueueing the same buffer each time, but with a incremented inStartTime.   What would cause AudioQueueEnqueueBufferWithParameters to ignore my inStartTime?

```
Frames in buffer: 11025
intended playtime = 0.000000
actual playtime = 0.000000
intended playtime = 99225.000000
actual playtime = 11025.000000
intended playtime = 198450.000000
actual playtime = 22050.000000
intended playtime = 297675.000000
actual playtime = 33075.000000
.
.
.
```

Comment: I'm sure you've moved past this by now, but the answer provided is incorrect. As I note in my comment there, you can create a delay by setting the playback time: the only important thing is that the playback time of buffer n can't be earlier than the end of buffer n-1's playback.

Answer (score 0):

The start time parameter can not be used to create a delay between successive buffers in a running audio queue.  Buffers in a single running audio queue are always played back to back.

The way to create a delay in an audio queue is to count samples and fill some or all of some buffers with silence until it is time to start filling a buffer with your desired sound samples.

Comment: That's an interesting approach and I will certainly try it. I had tried the method I referred to based on [Apple Tech note 1718](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1718/_index.html).  That seemed to indicate you could schedule the buffers to create a delay.

Comment: This answer is wrong. You can create a delay by setting the playback time: the only important thing is that the playback time of buffer **n** can't be earlier than the end of buffer **n-1**'s playback. I'd downvote, but I don't have enough reputation. @hotpaw2, could you remove this answer?

Comment: Have you actually tested this on an iOS device?

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation found in *AudioQueue.h* (you can access it using XCode) on *AudioQueueEnqueueBufferWithParameters*'s parameter *inStartTime*:

*@param      inStartTime

...

Note: When specifying a start time for a buffer, if the buffer is not the first enqueued since AudioQueueStop or AudioQueueReset, it is normally necessary to call AudioQueueFlush before  AudioQueueEnqueueBufferWithParameters*

(for some reason the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioQueueReference/#//apple_ref/c/func/AudioQueueEnqueueBufferWithParameters) doesn't contain this note)

you have to call *AudioQueueFlush* prior enqueue. I know it's written *"...since AudioQueueStop or AudioQueueReset..."* but it also works with *AudioQueueStart*.

Comment: Can you please add the direct link to the documentation in addition to just coping and pasting the text?

Comment: Hi there, It seems the note I've pasted is not part of the official Apple online [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioQueueReference/#//apple_ref/c/func/AudioQueueEnqueueBufferWithParameters). I've read it by inspecting the AudioQueue.h source code via XCode.